# Android Open ListView from another ListView without intents

Tags: android

I searched allover but couldn't find any clear answer. I have a ListView declared in A customView and I would like to open another ListView when clicking on an Item. 
I managed to do that by changing the adapter each time I click on an item on the Main ListView and show a pseudo new ListView. However this is not a stable solution.

I would like to know how can I instantiate a new listView without using intents or without having to change the adapter each time I want a new list output. I would want to create an entirely new ListView without direct connection to the initial one.

Comment: You could create a new `ListView` like you would any other `View` but you will still need an `Adapter` to populate the list.

Comment: Use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: aham. So basically I would need to create for each layer a listview, feed tha data through the adapter and perhaps a ViewHolder adn load it in when I click on the main ListView. I was thinking on the same approach. However do I need to addView when clicking and set the layout to visible or is there another nicer approach?

Comment: Regarfing the Expandable list, I know about it but I don't want to expand I want to switch the whole layout to a complete new list.

Comment: If you don't want to open a new `Activity` then that would work. If there aren't going to be many `ListView`s then you could create them and toggle `visibility`, I suppose if you don't want to just change the `Adapter`.

Comment: Activity remains constant, the Listviews are nested in a Fragment and the state remains intact aswell. The problem is I have quite many ListViews, I was thinking to create Methods that return ListViews and have a base Layout and poplate this with these methods, based on item selection. However, the resource recycling part comes in play, hence I want to keep a saved state and based on the selected option to store the data somehow. I don't have code hence I am currntly thinking of the best way to implement. Do you maybe know some sample apps ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `ListFragment` with `FrameLayout` in layout file? and just switch fragment when click on list item

Comment: Is it save to nest fragments in other fragments when I have a view pager and futurely would probably have a Navigation drawer?

Comment: i mean you might have `Activity` with `FrameLayout` inside then you just add first `ListFragment` and replace by second `ListFragment` later on and you can also use this `FrameLayout` for contain other fragment in the future also

Comment: Yeah but its to risky because you might have to handle lifecycle behaviour and if you have nested fragments the complexity rises. I sticked to plain old custom Views and let the initial fragment where my root custom view is declared handle all the other stuff. And it works. However thanks for the input. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I created in the CustomView several LinearLayouts for each listview one root layout. I have also created an individual class for each listView and used the same CustomAdapter and ViewHolder throughout. What I additionally used were interfaces that I declared in each List View class, with a method that tracks the row number. Based on this I implemented all the interfaces in the CustomView and listened to the clicked rows. At last, I then created animation methods and played with the visibilities. 
By the way, instead of setting the List views to INVISIBLE i set them to GONE, hence there are quite manny the GPU doesn't need to recalculate the layout bounds.
Hope that helps cheers.
The method that i Place in the customView init() looks like this:

The interface listener must be implemented on "this" context of the CustomView, otherwise NUllPointerException hence the ListView doesn't know where to listen too.